# How to run TestNG tests in libGDX project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, libgdx, build.gradle

everyone.

I'm using Intellij IDEA and last libGDX version.

I've checked [some documentation](http://testng.org/doc/download.html) on adding TestNG dependency to build.gradle file. So, my build.grade is looking like this at the moment.

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }

        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.6.0'
        classpath 'org.testng:testng:6.9.4'

    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"


    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "SiliconStory"
        gdxVersion = '1.6.5'
        roboVMVersion = '1.6.0'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.6.0'
        aiVersion = '1.5.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        jcenter()
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.9.4'
    }

    test{
        useTestNG();
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    }
}

project(":html") {
    apply plugin: "gwt"
    apply plugin: "war"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"

    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.9.4'

    }

    test{
        useTestNG();
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

I've created the test file, and the main problem - IDEA "can not resolve symbol" of TestNG classes. So, to solve the problem, I just adding library "testing-6.9.4", which is testNG library, to the classpath of the project.

If i try to start the test, compilaton fails. All the errors are about missing the TestNG package. I try to refresh all the grade projects, and again in my test-file all annotations and imports of testNG are red with 
warnings and proposals to add library of testNG to the class path.

So... What should I do?

PS: Here I'll provide you will the text of test, if it is necessary.

```
public class BarTest {
    Bar bar;
    @org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        bar = new Bar();
    }

    @Test
    public void costAndCashTest(){
        double cost = bar.getCost();
        assertTrue(cost < 20.1);
    }

    @org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution! 
The only thing we should add is a line:

```
sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs = ["Tests/"]
```

To the build.gradle file in the core directory. "Tests/" folder is the special directory for all the tests in the core module of the project.

So, the build.gradle files text should be looking like this:

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]


eclipse.project {
    name = appName + "-core"
}
sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs = ["Tests/"]
```